# angular how to do a form submittion with ajax

Tags: php, html, angularjs, codeigniter

Hello I'm new to angular and I have being trying to submit a form and check in my mysql database if the user is present. all of my code work because when I put the json directly in my php/codeigniter code i get the employee that im looking for. I think my problem is transferring the data from my angular to php.

this is my html

```
<div class="login-content">
    <form ng-controller="loginController" ng-submit="processForm()" class='margin-bottom-0' accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="form-group m-b-20">
            <input type="text" ng-model="formData.AccessKey" required="true" id="AccessKey" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Access Key" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group m-b-20">
            <input type="password" ng-model="formData.Password" required="true" id="Password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="login-buttons">
            <button type="submit" name="IsPostBack" value="true" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is my angular code

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http){

$scope.processForm = function(){
    $http({
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : 'http://localhost:8888/employees/login',
        data    : $scope.formData = {},
        header  : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data);

        })
};

});
```

this is my php im using codeigniter framework. this is the controller

```
public function login()
{
    $this->employees_model->login();
}
```

this is my model in php

```
public function login()
{
    $data = $this->input->get('data');

    //$data = '{"AccessKey":"candoa01@gmail.com","Password":"candoa21"}';
    $data =  json_decode($data);

    $AccessKey = $data->AccessKey;
    $Password = $data->Password;

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM Employees
            WHERE Employees.AccessKey = ?
            AND Employees.Password = ?";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($AccessKey, $Password));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $query = json_encode($query->result());
        return $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output($query);
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Invalid AccessKey Or Password';
    }
}
```

this is the error im getting

Trying to get property of non-object in line 173

line 173 $AccessKey = $data->AccessKey;

so somehow i don't think im passing the values correctly.

Comment: Can you please log this in Angular and see what you are passing? `$scope.formData`

Comment: im getting this error in the console.log:          XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/employees/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app:8888' is therefore not allowed access. http://app:8888 is my current app and im trying to get info in http://localhost:8888/employees/login. formData is passing {"AccessKey":"candoa01@gmail.com","Password":"candoa21"}

Comment: have a read on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add this header see what will happen:

```
{"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the next line in your angular code will always resets your formData before sending request:

```
    data    : $scope.formData = {},
```

Therefore, change it to

```
    data    : $scope.formData,
```

Second, I don't think data config works with GET method. Try POST instead if possible:

```
    method  : 'POST',
```

I don't know what PHP framework you are using, but it seems good to me. At least the conversations worked in my case by simply fixing the above points.

Maybe you want to log all requests at your server side first when you faced similar issues in the future:

```
Log::info($this->input->all()); // Something like this? I'm guessing.
```

Comment: I managed to fix the header problem but I can pass the value to php. I get Trying to get property of non-object. so i think im not sending anything. I change my code and still i can't pass the value.

Comment: What's your $data before json_decode, empty string?